# disable IPV6 on specific interface with redhat on vmware

Tags: networking, ipv6, redhat-enterprise-linux, esxi

I tried to disable IPv6 on specific interface using IPV6INIT=no on the interface script.
its working great on all server accept ones that run on Vmware.

any idea?

im using redhat 5.2, on vmware ESX